# Loading an external page into a div with Jquery strips out the .html and throws an error page

Tags: jquery, html

I've been searching for a solution for last couple days and since I couldn't find one I thought I'd go ahead and see if anyone on here can help. I'm trying to have the content from external html pages (same domain - just separate pages, ie) `about.html`, `contact.html`, etc) show up on my main `index.html` page within the div `#topContent` when the various nav links are clicked (ie. About, contact, etc). I'm hoping by storing the site's "main content" on external pages I can avoid refreshes between nav selections.

So far I'm able to make the default page load (an external - `main.html` doc), but for some reason when I click the nav links I am redirected to another page which creates an error because the ".html" is stripped away from the path (Expecting to see: site.com/about.html -- Actually shows: site.com/about )

My current changes are live here: http://staging-site.site44.com/ and I would create a jsFiddle file, but this setup involves loading multiple html files so I don't think I can do that with jsFiddle.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

HTML

```
    <nav id="headerNav">

            <ul class="navList">
                <li class="navItem"><a href="products" id="home" class="nav">Products</a></li>
                <li class="navItem"><a href="about" id="about" class="nav">About</a></li>
                <li class="navItem"><a href="portfolio" id="portfolio" class="nav">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li class="navItem"><a href="contact" id="contact" class="nav">Contact</a></li>
            </ul> 

        </nav>


    </div>

</div>

<!-- topMain -->
<div id="topContentWrapper">

     <div id="topContent">





    </div>



</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Load default page content of main.html
$("#topContent").load("main.html");

$("#home").click(function() {
//load home.html on click
    $("topContent").load("home.html");
});

$("#products").click(function() {
//load home.html on click
    $("topContent").load("products.html");
});

$("#about").click(function() {
//load home.html on click
    $("topContent").load('about.html #topContent');
});

$("#portfolio").click(function() {
//load home.html on click
    $("topContent").load("portfolio.html");
});
 });
```

Comment: Do you have any htaccess rewrites?

Comment: `<li class="navItem"><a href="products" id="home" class="nav">` In your example HTML, which I assume is one of the files you are loading, the href doesn't have HTML appended. Is that HTML the result or what you are trying to load?

Comment: @jtheman - no, I don't have any htaccess rewrites

Comment: @crush - the example HTML is within the index.html file. I realized the href doesn't have HTML appended when you mentioned that. I have changed the href html to: href="#" and within the JS it should slot in the correct .html file based on the id of that li, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Javascript is wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Load default page content of main.html
$("#topContent").load("main.html");

$("#home").click(function(e) {
//load home.html on click
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#topContent").load("home.html");
});

$("#products").click(function(e) {
//load home.html on click
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#topContent").load("products.html");
});

$("#about").click(function(e) {
//load home.html on click
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#topContent").load('about.html');
});

$("#portfolio").click(function(e) {
//load home.html on click
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#topContent").load("portfolio.html");
});
 });
```

you were missing the "#" selector in your jQuery. Thus, your click wasn't able to load anything into the topContent element. Also you need to add e.preventDefault() to prevent the links from attempting to follow the href when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem come from href not setted correctly, missing '.html' and from $('topContent') selector, missing '#'. BTW, you have to prevent default behaviour on 'A' tag when clicked.

See following code, using refactorization: {better practice}

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Load default page content of main.html
   $("#topContent").load("main.html");

   $(".nav").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#topContent").load($(this).attr('href')+".html");
   });

 });
```

Comment: Let me rephrase that. This is a good idea, but doesn't explain why the OP was having issues getting his to work.

Comment: @rush Sorry, which hack are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do, first include the .html in the anchor.

```
<ul class="navList" id="main-menu">
    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then use one jQuery function for all of them:

```
$('#main-menu a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // stops the page redirect

    var htmlFile = $(this).attr('href');    // gets href value from the anchor
    $.get(htmlFile, function(data) {        // you could use get/ajax/load
        $('#topContent').html(data);
    });
});
```

That's off the top of my head so may have slight errors.

**Additional note:** You don't need that many classes.

Comment: I tried your solution but it opened to the content page (ex. about.html) rather than importing the content onto the index.html page. As for the classes - I'm almost certain I have too many haha still new to writing code and slowly learning the best ways to condense.

Answer (score 0):

the below script worked on the chrome console

```
$('#topContent').load('about.html', function() {

});
```

the problem is in `href="pagename"`, put `href="#"` and then use the below function

```
$("#about").click(function() {

$('#topContent').load('about.html', function() {

});
});
```

Comment: what does the `function()` within the `.load()` do? **IMA Noob lol